# GDAL doesn't read TIFF in Python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to open a GeoTIFF using the following code:

```
filename = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\grdtocsv\ers_to_tiff\old.tiff"
sourceds = gdal.Open(filename)
```

The thing is that I dont get any error and the 'sourceds' is empty

The version of GDAL is 3.4.3

Comment: Enable exceptions then see what error you get: https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-bindings-do-not-raise-exceptions-unless-you-explicitly-call-useexceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "gotcha" in the GDAL Python bindings.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions() # <---- Add this line
gdal.open(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\grdtocsv\ers_to_tiff\old.tiff')
```

https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-bindings-do-not-raise-exceptions-unless-you-explicitly-call-useexceptions